getopt with several `--`
I have a script with this usage:
myscript [options] positional-args... -- [fwd-params]

Because [options] can have long, or short variants, I like using getopt.  But I'm having troubles.
I use getopt like this:
args=$(getopt -o a:,b --long alpha:,gamma -- "$@")
eval set -- "$args"
while : ; do 
  case "$1" in
    -a | --alpha) a="$2" ; shift 2 ;; 
    -b          ) b=true ; shift   ;;
    --gamma     ) g=true ; shift   ;;
    -- )          shift  ; break   ;; 
  esac
done

positionals=()
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
  case "$1" in
    *  ) positionals+=("$1"); shift ;;
    -- ) shift ; break ;;
  esac
done

# What-ever is left in "$@" needs to be forwarded to another program

backend "$@"

This works great if I don't have any [fwd-params]:
$ getopt -o a:,b -- -a 1 -b pos1 pos2
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2'
            ^-- getopt adds this to help me find 
                the end-of-options/start-of-positionals

But it falls apart if the user defined any [fwd-params].  Here's my desired output:
$ getopt -o a:,b -- -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 -- fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2' '--' 'fwd1'
                              ^
                              \-   I'll use this to delimit 
                                   the positional arguments 
                                   from the forwarding ones.

And here's what I actually get.  The user's intentional -- has been filtered out.
$ getopt -o a:,b -- -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 -- fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2' 'fwd1'

What's the best way to delimit my positional-arguments from the forwarding ones?

See the part about "If  the  first  character  is '+'" in the man page of the getopt implementation from util-linux.

Well, if the user passes the arguments -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 -- fwd1, getopt takes the -- as the marker making all following arguments non-options. It's not a positional argument itself here.
If you want the -- to appear as-is, your user would have to explicly add the marker, and another -- one after to separate the two sets of positionals, e.g.:
$ getopt -o a:,b -- -a 1 -b -- pos1 pos2 -- fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2' '--' 'fwd1'

or, you could prefix the set of option characters with a + to ask for the POSIX behaviour, where any non-option marks the end of options. That way, the -- in your example would no longer be the marker, but a positional in itself:
$ getopt -o +a:,b -- -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 -- fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2' '--' 'fwd1'

But note that if you don't have positional arguments in the first set, the user will still need to manually add a total of two --s:
$ getopt -o +a:,b -- -a 1 -b -- -- fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- '--' 'fwd1'


I would likely do something similar to what GNU Parallel does, and use some other fixed string to separate the two types of positionals. E.g. have the script look for a :: instead, leaving -- for getopt. So the user would enter -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 :: fwd1 (with or without a  --):
$ getopt -o +a:,b -- -a 1 -b pos1 pos2 :: fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- 'pos1' 'pos2' '::' 'fwd1'

or with no positionals in the first set:
$ getopt -o +a:,b -- -a 1 -b :: fwd1
 -a '1' -b -- '::' 'fwd1'


In my case, there must always be at least 1 positional arg.  So the + solution is perfect.  I must have read that man page 20 times, but I never quite comprehended "If the first character is '+', ... parsing stops as soon as the first non-option parameter ... is found ... . The remaining parameters are all interpreted as non-option parameters."  Thanks!
